# Map label date with database date

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
Visit_Date="2012-02-13 15:01:36.000"
```

getting date from database like above and my label date is in this format

```
label1.text="13-Feb-2012"
```

i have to map label date with database date 
using  my query like this

```
Select * From User_Master Where date='"+label1.text+"';
```

How i do get this record using code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Select * From User_Master
Where replace(Convert(varchar,Visit_Date,106),' ','-')='"+label1.text+"';
```

see sql fiddle [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/3254)

Comment: i have one problem joe how i use between Visit_Date to get record

Comment: select * from table where replace(Convert(varchar,Visit_Date,106),' ','-')
BETWEEN '14-Jul-2012' and '16-Aug-2012'

Comment: @lax: you cannot use between here.. becoz we are converting the Visit_date to string

Comment: @lax: You could do something like this    select * from table where Visit_Date BETWEEN Convert.ToDateTime('14-Aug-2012') and Convert.ToDateTime('16-Aug-2012')

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15315/discussion-between-joe-g-joseph-and-lax)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it won't match because your visit date is for 13th Feb and your label date is for 13th August, if that's the record that are comparing.

Second, SQL does an implicit convert for date types and passing a valid date text would allow you to successfully compare between dates ([Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx)). The only thing you have to be careful about is the where you've got date time and you only want to compare on the date. So something like this:

```
Select * From User_Master Where Convert(varchar(10),visit_date,101) ="+label1.text+"';
```

Answer (score 0):

-- This will work for you

```
 Select * From User_Master Where Convert(varchar,date,106) ='"+label1.text+"';
```

-- the below format gives you output as you want

```
 SELECT convert(datetime, '23 OCT 2016', 106) -- dd mon yyyy

 select convert(varchar, getdate(), 106) -- output 13 August 2012
```

refer to below link to see more formats
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx

good link
http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Comment: @lax The `Convert(varchar,date,106)` in the select statement converts your date to this format 13-Aug-2012. It will only compare date not time.

Comment: @lax In the question your label date is not equal to the Visit Date. In label you have 13-Aug-2012 and in visit date you have 2012-02-13 ( 2012 - Feb - 13 ) already mentioned by Divi